# How to use php isset with a function?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

The following IF statement causes ZendFramework to error (with a blank screen). PhpStorm indicates **expected variable** with a red indicator after ('page_reference').  Is there a way I may execute this IF statement without causing an error?

```
if ( isset( $this->params()->fromRoute('page_reference') ) ) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: `$this->params()->fromRoute('page_reference')` is not a variable, what do you expect from `isset` to do here?

Comment: You probably want `!empty`

Comment: !empty resolves this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [php documentation `isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is meant to be used in a variable context.

> Warning
>   isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.

In this case it's possible to solve this in a simple way:

```
if ( $this->params()->fromRoute('page_reference') !== null ) {

} else {

}
```

Notice, the [second parameter of fromRoute](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/Plugin/Params.php#L96-L104) is `$default = null`, and can be used to pass the expected value when the 'page_reference' is not defined.